# Jquery.js error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main page with 2 buttons linked to a registration page and the other to a login page. In the chrome debugger it shows the error:

```
jquery.js:2 
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 
html/first-time-login/first-time-login.php
    at Function.fb.error (jquery.js:2)
    at fb.tokenize (jquery.js:2)
    at fb.select (jquery.js:2)
    at Function.fb [as find] (jquery.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.find (jquery.js:2)
    at m.fn.init (jquery.js:2)
    at m (jquery.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (custom.js:92)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.js:3)
```

Here is my HTML code for the links:

```
<a href="html/login/login.php" class="wow fadeInUp btn btn-default hvr-bounce-to-top smoothScroll" data-wow-delay="1.3s">Login</a>
<a href="html/first-time-login/first-time-login.php" class="wow fadeInUp btn btn-default hvr-bounce-to-top smoothScroll" data-wow-delay="1.3s">register</a>
```

Also here is my custom.js line 92 code:

```
scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 49
```

That line is in this function:

```
$(function() {
        $('#home a, .navbar-default a').bind('click', function(event) {
            var $anchor = $(this);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 49
            }, 1000);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Also if you wanted to know I am using a template. I forgot exactly where I got it from, though. 
Thanks to anyone for helping me

Comment: You need to paste your custom javascript (see custom.js at line 92)

Comment: It looks like you have some code that's using the `href` attribute as a selector, e.g. `$(this.href)`

Comment: I even tried changing the links to different one's but, it is still now working. All the other questions I saw said the same exact things: to change the links cause jquery is interpreting it in a different way

Comment: The error `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ` at `jquery.js:2` typically means: the selector is not a valid css selector. So while the construction `$($anchor.attr('href'))` isn't inherently wrong, this error message is telling you that whatever the value of `$anchor.attr('href')` is, it is not a valid css selector. Can you post the value of `$anchor.attr('href')`?

Comment: Do you know how to use javascript? Comment the line where you include custom.js. It is obviously giving an error. Maybe it is related to the link having these classes: `class="wow fadeInUp btn btn-default hvr-bounce-to-top smoothScroll"` I bet that the error will be gone when you delete the `smoothScroll` class there. You must be using a scrolling javascript plugin that doesn't have what it needs to work, so it's giving an error. I guess smoothscroll is for single page apps, it surely expects the `href` attribute of your link to be the `id` of an element in the same page so it can scroll

Comment: chiliNUT How exactly am I supposed to display the value of that. I kept the function the line 92 is on. I also know that I should use console.log or alert(); but, how exactly should I implement it? I am kind of new to JavaScript

Comment: @JorgeeFG I commented out the custom.js inclusion line and it works. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the class `smoothScroll` of your link `class` attribute.

Example:

`<a href="html/first-time-login/first-time-login.php" class="wow fadeInUp btn btn-default hvr-bounce-to-top" data-wow-delay="1.3s">register</a>`

I think `smoothScroll` expects that the `href` attribute contains the `id` (or a valid JQuery selector string) of another element in the same page, so it can scroll down or up to this element.
Since this is not happening in your page, it trhows an error.

Comment: @AbhinavVemulapalli remove the other classes also. Just keep `btn`abd `btn-default` and see which one is causing trouble. The classes per-se don't cause trouble, but in this case, they could be used by some JavaScript to identify objects they should manage, and then there is something missing.